# How to add a class to an input when input containes a certain value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

i have a form with 4 input fields.

```
<input class='radio' type='radio' name='radiovote' value='<?php echo $key; ?>'>
<input class='radio' type='radio' name='radiovote' value='<?php echo $key; ?>'>
<input class='radio' type='radio' name='radiovote' value='<?php echo $key; ?>'>
<input class='radio' type='radio' name='radiovote' value='<?php echo $key; ?>'>
```

One of these input has the value `2`. I want to add a class `alert-success` to this input field which contains the value `2`

I tried this but it does not work:

```
$('input:contains("2")').closest('.radio').addClass('alert alert-success');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this happen on page load(not after the page is loaded) .You can use jQuery's `.filter()`to filter by value:

```
$('input').filter('[value=2]').addClass('alert alert-success');
```

If the value changes to 2 after the page is loaded. You need to attach an event:

```
$('input').change((event) => {
   $(this).addClass('alert alert-success');
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Works great. Can i also add `checked` to that input field with value 2 and how should i do that?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can chain another `.filter(':checked')`

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped to solve you issue, do not forget to mark it as a correct answer :)